# How do I get MTLS to work using Java with multiple Client Keys with aliases and same dname?

Tags: java, ssl, mtls

I have the following keystore

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias client -keyalg $keyalg -keysize $keysize -storetype $storetype -keystore $keystore -validity $validity -storepass $password -dname "CN=client"
keytool -genkeypair -alias client2 -keyalg $keyalg -keysize $keysize -storetype $storetype -keystore $keystore -validity $validity -storepass $password -dname "CN=client"
keytool -genkeypair -alias client3 -keyalg $keyalg -keysize $keysize -storetype $storetype -keystore $keystore -validity $validity -storepass $password -dname "CN=client"
```

and then I add the server to the trust store and vice versa

```
keytool -importcert -file $certificate -alias $alias -keystore $server_truststore -noprompt -storepass $password
keytool -importcert -file $server_cert -alias server-cert -keystore $truststore -noprompt -storepass $password
```

But when I run the following...

```java
    @Bean
    public Step step1(
            JobRepository jobRepository,
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager
    ) {
        return new StepBuilder("my-step", jobRepository)
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    // Load the p12 file from the classpath
                    InputStream keystoreInputStream = new ClassPathResource("ssl/client.p12").getInputStream();

                    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
                    ks.load(keystoreInputStream, "changeit".toCharArray());

                    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                    keyManagerFactory.init(ks, "changeit".toCharArray());

                    InputStream truststoreInputStream = new ClassPathResource("ssl/truststore.p12").getInputStream();
                    KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
                    ts.load(truststoreInputStream, "changeit".toCharArray());


                    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                    trustManagerFactory.init(ts);

                    SslContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                            .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
                            .trustManager(trustManagerFactory);
                    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                            .secure(sslContextSpec -> {
                                try {
                                    sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContextBuilder.build());
                                } catch (SSLException e) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                }
                            });

                    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                            .build();

                    String result = webClient.get()
                            .uri("https://localhost:8443/test")
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(String.class)
                            .block();
                    System.out.println(result);
                    return null;
                }, transactionManager)
                .build();
    }
```

I get an error

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365) ~[na:na]...
```

I can get it to work if I change to

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias client -keyalg $keyalg -keysize $keysize -storetype $storetype -keystore $keystore -validity $validity -storepass $password -dname "CN=client"
keytool -genkeypair -alias client2 -keyalg $keyalg -keysize $keysize -storetype $storetype -keystore $keystore -validity $validity -storepass $password -dname "CN=client2"
keytool -genkeypair -alias client3 -keyalg $keyalg -keysize $keysize -storetype $storetype -keystore $keystore -validity $validity -storepass $password -dname "CN=client3"
```

But that messes up something else I am trying to do. So basically what I would like to know how Java selects the correct alias and why can't I have multiple with the same dn?

I also tried extending the `X509ExtendedKeyManager` but that didn't seem to help